# 500 Internal Server Error from Saving to couchDb

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am trying to save a document to my couch database. Here is the code I use to make the call

```
function splitIntoItemsThenSendItemsToCouch(dumpDoc){
  var items = dumpDoc.children[0].children[0].children;
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var doc = { "_id":items[i].children[1].textContent, "_attachments": {"content_type":"text\/plain","data":window.btoa(items[i].outerHTML)}}
    db.saveDoc(doc)
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the error log I get from couch while trying to save a document.

```
[Tue, 07 Jul 2015 17:42:19 GMT] [error] [<0.112.0>] function_clause error in HTTP request
[Tue, 07 Jul 2015 17:42:19 GMT] [info] [<0.112.0>] Stacktrace: [{couch_doc,'-transfer_fields/2-fun-0-',
                                    [{<<"content_type">>,<<"text/plain">>}],
                                    [{file,"couch_doc.erl"},{line,227}]},
                                {lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1224}]},
                                {couch_doc,transfer_fields,2,
                                    [{file,"couch_doc.erl"},{line,227}]},
                                {couch_httpd_db,couch_doc_from_req,3,
                                    [{file,"couch_httpd_db.erl"},{line,793}]},
                                {couch_httpd_db,db_doc_req,3,
                                    [{file,"couch_httpd_db.erl"},{line,582}]},
                                {couch_httpd_db,do_db_req,2,
                                    [{file,"couch_httpd_db.erl"},{line,234}]},
                                {couch_httpd,handle_request_int,5,
                                    [{file,"couch_httpd.erl"},{line,318}]},
                                {mochiweb_http,headers,5,
                                    [{file,"mochiweb_http.erl"},{line,94}]}]
[Tue, 07 Jul 2015 17:42:19 GMT] [info] [<0.112.0>] 192.168.1.25 - - PUT /items4493/C-11034 500
[Tue, 07 Jul 2015 17:42:19 GMT] [error] [<0.112.0>] httpd 500 error response:
 {"error":"unknown_error","reason":"function_clause"}
```

I have tried quite a few things already, and will continue to do so. If any of you had a similar problem please let me know. 
Also I am a little illiterate when it comes to the couch error log. I think I understand the gist of it, but maybe I do not so if you could also help me make a little more sense out of this log.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so lucky that I debugged this pretty fast. Following the direction of https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Inline_Attachments I realised that I made a silly mistake. I forgot to name the attached file itself. so I revise the line

```
  var doc = { "_id":items[i].children[1].textContent, "_attachments": {"content_type":"text\/plain","data":window.btoa(items[i].outerHTML)}}
```

into

```
    var doc = {"_id":items[0].children[1].textContent, "_attachments": {"items_metadata":{"content_type":"text\/plain","data":window.btoa(items[0].outerHTML)}}}
```